# How to build this kind of Layouts in blade.php?

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

Below is my code. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmEob.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 border-left">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What have tried so far ? Please provide a minimal reproducible  example of your effort to achieve this ? Read here [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service. This forum is for posting detailed complete questions as per the recommendations in the comment by @AlwaysHelping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### NOTE:

Your question does not fit to be in SO. You should provide a minimal code that you tried but failed to get what you wanted. Anyhow, I'm sharing with you the approach I use to implement such layouts. Then I'll leave it up to you to complete your code. Should you have any problems, feel free to ask.

## Step 1

I see two large columns divided by a vertical separator.

```
<div class="row">
  <section class="col-8"></section>
  <section class="col-4"></section>
</div>
```

Note: I'll leave the vertical line implementation up to you.

## Step 2 (Section I)

It can be considered a container having two columns. First column contains `big-box` and the second column contains four `small-box's`. Let us edit the code for section I `<section class="col-8"></section>`

```
<section class="col-8 row">
  <div class="col-6 big-box"></div>
  <div class="col-6 container-small-boxes></div>
</section>
```

Next, we populate the div having `container-small-boxes` with small boxes.

```
<div class="col-6 container-small-boxes row">
  <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
  <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
  <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
  <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
</div>
```

The complete code for `section I` will look like

```
<section class="col-8 row">
  <div class="col-6 big-box">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 container-small-boxes row">
    <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
    <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
    <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
    <div class="col-6 small-box"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Next, there are three steps that I leave for you to try and get your hands dirty.

## Step 3 (Section II)

...

## Step 4 (Implement the code for `small-box` and `big-box`)

...

## Step 5 (Combine all code)

...

Should you have any problem, feel free to comment.

Comment: thanks bro... I am trying to implement as your methods. If I get any problem I will comment.